# Find the sum of all quantities per item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the NorthWind database and my point is to select the total amount of shipped orders per City in one row. Sorry for dummy question but I am new in Sql

```
select e.FirstName , o.ShipCity, od.UnitPrice,Sum(od.Quantity), 
sum(od.Quantity*od.UnitPrice) from [Order Details] as od 
inner join Products as p on p.ProductID=od.ProductID
inner join Orders as o on o.OrderID =od.OrderID
inner join Employees as e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
where o.ShipCity= 'Graz' and o.isCanceled !=1 and e.FirstName ='Nancy'
group by e.FirstName , o.ShipCity,od.UnitPrice
```

[image]

Comment: Add code as text not as image. Add the dbms tag

Comment: You need to group your query by `firstName` and `ShipCity`, then get `sum` of the `quantity`

Comment: As @jens says... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475

Answer (score 1):

=>

```
select e.firstName , o.ShipCity , sum ( od.Quantity) from [ order Details ] as od 
inner join Orders  as o on o.OrderId = od.OrderId
inner join Employees as e on e.employeeID=o.EmployeeID
where o.shipcity = 'Graz'and o.iscanceled !=1 and e.firstname='Nancy'
group by e.firstName , o.ShipCity
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount per city you must remove `FirstName` and `UnitPrice` from your select.

```
select o.ShipCity,
   Sum(od.Quantity), 
   sum(od.Quantity*od.UnitPrice) 
from [Order Details] as od 
inner join Products as p on p.ProductID=od.ProductID
inner join Orders as o on o.OrderID =od.OrderID
inner join Employees as e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
where o.ShipCity= 'Graz' and o.isCanceled !=1 and e.FirstName ='Nancy'
group by o.ShipCity
```